# How to auto-reload current file in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

Sometimes I would like to modify files in another text editor and switch back, but Sublime Text 3 wouldn't reload the current file that I edited before.

How do I get it to reload the file automatically?

Answer (score 7):

I believe [AutoRefresh](https://github.com/Waterflames/AutoRefresh) should do the trick.

You can also reload the file manually using the menu `File`->`Revert File`

Comment: AutoRefresh is also available on Package Control https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Auto%20Refresh

Answer (score 5):

There's a setting to control whether you get to see a prompt, but otherwise Sublime Text reloads the file automatically by default.

See the setting in `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
// Always prompt before reloading a file, even if the file hasn't been
// modified. The default behavior is to automatically reload a file if it
// hasn't been edited. If a file has unsaved changes, a prompt will always
// be shown.
"always_prompt_for_file_reload": false
```

Comment: this feature won't auto reload/refresh the file, it'll just skip the prompt when you change tabs or focus out and back to Sublime.

Comment: Yeah I agree with  João Ciocca (user:1985023) - with the setting, the file just becomes out of date.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is changed on disk, and is open in Sublime, the default behavior is a dialog window that prompts to see if you want to reload the file.

If you have previously selected "Ignore All" when prompted with that dialog for that particular file, then Sublime's behavior for that file will be changed. The *file view* setting will be changed from `True` to `False` for `reload_file_on_change`.[1]

You can get the current file view setting (for whichever file is open in your view) by typing this in the console[2]:

```
view.settings().get('reload_file_on_change')
```

And can you set the current file view setting back to `True` with this[3]:

```
view.settings().set('reload_file_on_change', True)
```

---

1. I searched ["ignore all" sublime reload save] to find this question/comment from thundt and the answer from bschaaf in the [Sublime Forum: Ignore All when unsaved changes and file changed on disk is not helpful!](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/ignore-all-when-unsaved-changes-and-file-changed-on-disk-is-not-helpful/62643)
2. Found via [Sublime Text Docs > Settings > Troubleshooting](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/settings.html#troubleshooting)
3. Found via [Sublime Text API Reference > Settings > .set](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.Settings.set)