# Auto refresh in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

I want Sublime Text to auto reload files when they are changed in the hard disk (by some process else). Although I am not expecting to have my code open in different places, I use the editor to see resulting files, which is why this feature is crucial to my coding setup. I’ve figured out the option to prompt for the reload as below. But my issue is, it takes a long time for Sublime Text to realize the file has changed and give me the prompt. The files are in a Linux server and I am accessing them through Samba in Windows. Previously I've used Notepad++ which instantly recognize the change and prompt me to reload - so this is not to do with the file systems or hardware. Is there a way to achieve this in Sublime Text or VSCode?

```
"always_prompt_for_file_reload": true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto reload current file in sublime text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171356/how-to-auto-reload-current-file-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for an explanation as to why it's taking so long to reload (compared to Notepad++)